# RSA encryption in Snap

Tags: encryption, rsa, public-key-encryption

For AP Computer Science my class had to use Snap whose source can be found at https://github.com/jmoenig/Snap--Build-Your-Own-Blocks in class. We had to make a simple encryption algorithm using a Caesar cipher. I thought to myself, why can't you use something more secure?

So I tried making RSA encryption in Snap. I realize snaps computing limitations but wanted something a small as 1 bit or 2 bit encryption to work. My code can be found on [this webpage](https://snap.berkeley.edu/snapsource/snap.html#present:Username=honakerm18&ProjectName=U-RSA).

The code however does not work and I wanted to know if it was because my understanding of RSA was wrong or I missed a step in RSA. My end goal is for my code to be able to encrypt any text in 1 or 2 bit RSA.

Here is the actual code:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please post the code here, if possible.  Offsite hosted code is not recommended for SO questions.

Comment: @roelofs I just updates the post with the code

Comment: I commend you for thinking creatively on the problem. There really is no such thing as a 1-bit prime. There are two 2-bit primes, namely 2 and 3, but you can't really use 2 in RSA. Even 3 is too small, since the only exponent available would be 1, which is not really encryption. A similar argument prevents you from using 5 and 7. So 5 and 11 are the smallest primes you can use for textbook RSA.

Comment: @JamesKPolk What a fun exercise. I just spent 10 minutes calculating the public and private exponents for every possible combination of primes below the 5 and 11 pair in my head. RSA would work with such small primes in some cases (5 and 7), but the problem is of course that the public exponent and private exponent would need to be the same which should really not be the case for RSA.

Comment: @ArtjomB. so my code is right but I am using to small of numbers?

Comment: No, your code is not correct. You're doing simple division `j = (z+1) / n`, but you actually need modular inversion. That can be achieved by implementing the Extended Euclidean Algorithm. And yes, your numbers are too small as James already said.

Comment: @ArtjomB. okay so thanks for your feedback and how would I do modular inversion? What numbers would be the right size? what happens if they are to small?